# How to use share button where it will display the meta og:tags

Tags: php, jquery

I am trying to make a facebook share button popup within the same page to share a specific link based on the specific url , i used this code and it works but all it gives me is the url. I would like it to look like this [image: facebook share]

my current code i have is this

```
<li> <a
id="fb-share"
style='text-decoration:none;'
type="icon_link"
onClick="window.open(
    'http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?s=100&p[title]=YOUR_TITLE&p[summary]='
        + 'YOUR_DESCRIPTION&p[url]=YOUR_URL&p[images][0]=YOUR_IMAGE',
    'sharer',
    'toolbar=0,status=0,width=580,height=325');"
href="javascript: void(0)"
>

<img class="logo" src="images/facebook.png" width="60" height="50" alt="Our Facebook Page "></a></li>
```

it only displays the correct url.Not the title , description or image. The images, and description and title comes from the db

```
<meta property="og:title" content="<?php echo title; ?>">
```

the other issue is the

```
<meta property="og:image"
```

must this be a url or can it come from the db similar to the og:title? as each main image must be displayed differently based on specific url.

i currently have this , will this be able to display the image , i do see the image name

```
   <?php echo '<meta property="og:image" content="' . $image . '"/>'; ?>
```

Comment: Did you debugged it using FB debugger console ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Expected `OG tags` format,

```
<html prefix="og: http://ogp.me/ns#">
<head>
<title>The Rock (1996)</title>
<meta property="og:title" content="The Rock" />
<meta property="og:type" content="video.movie" />
<meta property="og:url" content="http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0117500/" />
<meta property="og:image" content="http://ia.media-imdb.com/images/rock.jpg" />
...
</head>

...
</html>
```

[Read more](http://ogp.me/)

Comment: i do have this , just its echo from the db. Do the OG tags display automatically?  i think it may be my javascript code?  + 'YOUR_DESCRIPTION&p[url]=YOUR_URL&p[images][0]=YOUR_IMAGE',  must i reference the description here and the image or not?

Comment: Yep, OG takes care of everything once you have provided it with correct parameters, and more you can test your OG tags in FB debugging tool